# Google trends in C#

Tags: c#, google-trends

I need to download google trends data in C#. Solutions described on stackoverflow do not work anymore [Oauth google trends download CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986758/oauth-google-trends-download-csv-file). Tried also to log to google account in IE and use the cookies as described here [download CSV from google Insight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078555/download-csv-from-google-insight). Not working.

When trying google api, as described here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth, I do not know which service to use for google trends. I also do not know, which service to enable in the google developers console. Is the google trends service not supported here? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you get any errors?

Comment: No, I receive a redirecting html.